# TikZ Feynman basic QED vertex misalignment

Tags: tikz-feynman

As the title says, I'm trying to draw the basic vertex of QED with TikZ Feynman, but whenever I run the following code in LuaLaTeX through TeXStudio

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [inline=(b.base), vertical=d to b]{
    a -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c,
    b -- [photon] d,
};
\end{document}
```

the following figure is produced, which clearly has the fermion lines not symmetrical with respect to the photon line

[image: QED basic vertex]

What is strange to me is when running in Overleaf the correct (symmetrical) vertex is produced. What am I missing here?

Comment: I checked thoroughly and I unfortunately have to confirm that this is a bug in TikZ.  I opened a ticket on the official bugtracker here: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/694

Comment: The regression was fixed in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/3e1952bdeb7886ad20e2a25896393a239f3aa2f0